# Django Empty Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to send news variable to my template:

```
try:
   news = News.objects.all()
except:
   #Is it programmatically true?
   news = ""
```

Is it programmatically true that I send news as empty srting when the query is empty?

Comment: How do you use the `news` variable in your template?

Comment: {% if news %} for loop {% endif %}  @RahulGupta

Comment: What sort of exceptions do you intend to catch with `try-except`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just send the `news` variable having value as `News.objects.all()` to your template.

There is no need to put a `try-except` block for `News.objects.all()` as it returns a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/) instance without raising an exception even if there were no objects in it (if that was the exception you were intending to catch).